# If $A\subseteq B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$, $A$ open, $B$ closed, then $\overline{A}\subseteq B$?

Tags: general-topology

If $A\subseteq B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$, $A$ open, $B$ closed, then $\overline{A}\subseteq B$? That is, $\partial A \subseteq B$?

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Comment: @AnuragA Well, is the statemet true?

Comment: What is your definition of $\bar{A}$? (There may be several equivalent definitions, but your question has a more immediate answer for some of them)

Comment: @ClementC. I use that the closure of $A$ is defined as the union of $A$ and its boundary $\partial A$.

Comment: And what is your definition of the boundary?

Comment: This will sound dumb, but what definition of boundary are you using? There again are several possible definitions, again equivalent... some actually even define it as $\bar{A}\setminus \mathring{A}$.

Comment: I see, if i use your definition @Bernard, it's kinda obvious, so i think i stick to it, since it in the end is equivalent with the one i use.

Comment: @Clement C: Great minds think together :o)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. $\overline A$ is the intersection of all closed subsets that contain $A$, hence it is contained in each of them.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
A\subset B\implies \overline{A}\subset \overline{B}=B
$$

Also
$$
\partial A =\overline{A}-A^o\subset \overline{A}\subset B
$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true and it is still true if $A$ isn't open.

Pf (w/o using A is open):

Definitions:

$$z \in \partial A \iff \exists \  r>0:D[z,r]\cap A \ne \emptyset \ne D[z,r]\cap A^c$$

$$z \in \partial B \iff \exists \  r>0:D[z,r]\cap B \ne \emptyset \ne D[z,r]\cap B^c$$

$$B \ \text{is closed} \iff \partial B \subseteq B \iff B = B^0 \cup \partial B$$

Now observe for $D[z,r]\cap A$:

$$D[z,r]\cap A \subseteq A \subseteq B \implies D[z,r]\cap B \ne \emptyset$$

Thus for $D[z,r]\cap A^c$:

$$D[z,r]\cap A^c \subseteq B \iff D[z,r] \subseteq B \iff z \in B^0$$

$$D[z,r]\cap A^c \subsetneq B \iff D[z,r]\cap B^c \ne \emptyset \iff z \in \partial B$$

In either case $z \in B$. QED